# deleting child component removes that component and all child components created after it

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I've run into a problem when I delete a component any component created after it deleted and then recreated. Component in question gets deleted and child component created after it get deleted and then recreated.

Is there a reason why this is happening?

[here is a video of it](http://maxniko.tinytake.com/sf/MTg3NTc2M182MDIyMzI5)

[Here is fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xk5yL3h8)

fiddle code:

```
Vue.component('column-component', {
    props: ["columnData", "uniqueId"],
    mounted: function() {
        console.log('mounting column: ' + this.uniqueId)
    },
    beforeDestroy: function() {
      console.log('removing: ' + this.uniqueId)
    },
    template: `
        <div style="float: left; padding: 10px; margin-right: 10px; border: 1px solid black;">aaa</div>`
})

Vue.component('row-component', {
    props: ["rowData", "uniqueId"],
    data: function data() {
      return {
        columns: [],
        columnCount: 0
       }
    },
    mounted: function() {
        console.log('mounting row: ' + this.uniqueId)
    },
    methods: { 
      addColumn() {
        console.log
                    var column = new Object()
          column.uniqueId = this.uniqueId +'.col.'+ this.columnCount
          this.columns.push(column)
          this.columnCount = this.columnCount + 1
      }
    },
    beforeDestroy: function() {
      console.log('removing: ' + this.uniqueId)
    },
    template: `
        <div>
         <div style="margin: 10px; padding: 20px; background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);">
            row component: {{rowData.text}}
            <div class="column" v-for="(column, index) in columns">
                    <column-component column-data="abc" :uniqueId="column.uniqueId"></column-component>
            </div>
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
            <div style="margin-top: 35px;">
                <button @click="addColumn()">add column</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>`
})

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    template: `
        <div>
            <div v-for="(row, index) in rows">
            <row-component :uniqueId="row.uniqueId" :row-data="row" :key="row.uniqueId"></row-component>
            <button @click="deleteThisRow(index)">remove row</button>
         </div> 
         <button @click="addRow()">add</button>
        </div> 
    `,
    data: {
        rows: [],
        rowCount: 0

    },
    mounted: function() {
        this.addRow()
      this.addRow()
      this.addRow()
    },
    methods: {
            addRow() {
            var row = new Object()
          row.uniqueId = 'row-' + this.rowCount
          row.text = 'row-'+(this.rows.length)
            this.rows.push(row)
          this.rowCount =  this.rowCount + 1
        },
        deleteThisRow: function(index) {
            this.rows.splice(index, 1)

            console.log(this.rows)
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updating entirely**

Ok, I learned something today:
[`:key` goes on the `v-for` element](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Components-and-v-for). A lot of the time, the `v-for` is on the component itself, so there's no distinction between putting the `key` on the component or the `v-for` element. You have a `div` with a `v-for` wrapping the component, and it makes a difference. It should be:

```
<div class="column" v-for="(column, index) in columns" :key="column.uniqueId">
    <column-component column-data="abc" :uniqueId="column.uniqueId"></column-component>
</div>
```

and

```
<div v-for="(row, index) in rows" :key="row.uniqueId">
    <row-component :uniqueId="row.uniqueId" :row-data="row"></row-component>
    <button @click="deleteThisRow(index)">remove row</button>
</div>
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xk5yL3h8/1/)

Comment: how about this: "[Vue warn]: Avoid using non-primitive value as key, use string/number value instead." I get that if I put in the object instead of string/number. Is it safe to ignore it? Also that thing comes up whenever I do something with the row, add a row, or add some stuff into the row etc. Wonder why they show that?

Comment: yes when not using key then it does not delete all components and recreates them BUT it still does not work correctly since it does not delete correct component. Any way around the warning or should I report it as a bug?

Comment: btw I just noticed that  using <row-component :uniqueId="row.uniqueId" :row-data="row" :key="row.uniqueId"></row-component> also works fine, so it does not matter if row or row.uniqueId is passed in, problem with this approach is that I want to wrap v-for inside a div and not use it directly on the component?

Comment: @maxit Got a real answer for you now.